# DevC++ works, but it has a weird problems during startup

Tags: c++

I'm using Dev C++ 5.11, downloaded from Sourceforge. It works properly, but always when I start it, it shows me [this](http://prntscr.com/7euwd4). Anyone knows what's the problem ??

Comment: I will use Visual Studio when I finish with my coutry+ competitions. Now I can only use DevC++ or CodeBlocks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i guess that's cause you dont have mingw installed on this directory check it out

Comment: I have it in DevCpp folder.

Comment: it is ask about default paths to compiler, is it show every time when you choose yes?

Comment: Every time I click on the DevC++ icon, it shows me that picture, and if I click yes or no, it will open DevC++ normally.

Comment: change default compiler, you have choose 32-bit version, compiler try found 64-bit version.